# Column name changes during creation of database in fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent NHibernate in my application. I want to create database tables from code using my mappings. All tables created but column for foreign key changed. My mapping for user class as

```
HasMany(Function(x) x.Friends).ForeignKeyConstraintName("UserID").Inverse()
```

and for friend class

```
References(Function(x) x.Users).Column("UserID")
```

But column created in friend table is Users_id. But I defined explicitly to be UserID. What am I doing wrong. Please help

Comment: It might be reserved keyword

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee: On which plat form is `"UserID"` a reserved keyword?  In `MySQL` it is not.

Answer (score 0):

What we would need is to introduce a custom convention. Please, read this for more details:

- [Fluent NHibernate conventions – examples](http://marcinobel.com/index.php/fluent-nhibernate-conventions-examples/) *(by Marcin Obel)*

An extract:

The DB generated with default Fluent-NHibernate setting *(in the example, but similar to our case)* was like this:

```
create table `Athlete` (
     ...
     Country_id INTEGER,
     ...
)
```

Then, this Convention was introduced:

> **ForeignKeyNameConvention** – says that name of every column containing foreign key id should consist of name of type which it points to with “Id” suffix.

```
public class ForeignKeyNameConvention : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Key.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
    }
}
```

And the SQL Scripts generated:

```
create table Athletes (
     ...
     CountryId INTEGER,
     ...
```